# Count the number of field by using AWK only and without other commands such as uniq

Tags: awk

Sample file

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk // file.txt 
a b
b c
c d
wolf@linux:~$
```

There are 2 fields, and 3 records in this example.

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk '{print NF}' file.txt 
2
2
2
wolf@linux:~$
```

To get a unique number, `uniq` command is used.

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk '{print NF}' file.txt | uniq
2
wolf@linux:~$
```

Would it be possible to count the number of fields by using `awk` alone without `uniq` in this example?

Desired Output

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk <???> file.txt
2
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: *"To get a unique number, uniq command is used."* Note that `uniq` will only remove *adjacent* duplicates

Comment: Cross-posted as https://www.reddit.com/user/w0lfcat/

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I'm not sure if the cross-posting ban applies to _other platforms_ beyond the StackExchange microcosm ...

Comment: @AdminBee The ban might not be applicable, but the principle behind it is relevant. Wolf is similarly enthusiastic all over reddit and ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's slightly unclear what you want (since `uniq` will only remove *adjacent* duplicates) however assuming you want to print all the unique field-counts across records *regardless of adjacency* you could use

```
awk '!seen[NF]++ {print NF}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> A BEGIN rule is executed once only, before the first input record is
> read.
>
> Likewise, an END rule is executed once only, after all the input is
> read.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html

E.g. 1

```
$ awk 'END {print NF}' file.txt 
2
```

E.g. 2

```
$ awk 'END {print NF " NF"}' file.txt
2 NF
```

E.g. 3

```
$ awk 'END {print NF,NR}' file.txt
2 3
```

E.g. 4

```
$ awk 'END {print NF " NF, " NR " NR"}' file.txt
2 NF, 3 NR
```